# comparing == characters in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to teach myself some scala. And I am stuck with something that seems arbitrary. I want to compare weather two characters are equal to each other.

**True example**

These return true as expected

```
"(" == "(" 
"(".equals("(")
```

**What I want to check**

```
"(an exampl(e))".toList(0)      // res : Char = (
```

**Somehow false**

These return false

```
"(an exampl(e))".toList(0).equals("(")
"(an exampl(e))".toList(0) == "("   
"(an exampl(e))".toList.head == "("
```

I think I am missing something here. Am I comparing the character value to a list pointer? If so, how can I check that the value of the item that I am pointing to is equal to `"("`?

Comment: You are not using an actual Scala version? This should give you a warning...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Short answer is You should compare with ')' not ")". The ")" is of type `String` not `Char`.

Using REPL, you can easily test it (note the type).

```
scala> ')'
res0: Char = )

scala> ")"
res1: String = )
```

The equals method is defined more or less like this `equals(obj: Any): Boolean`, so the code compiles doesn't matter what reference you pass to it as an argument. However the check is `false`, as the type is not the same.

By the way I think nicer way is to write your tests like this (without `.toList` as `.head` is defined in `StringOps` as well):

```
scala> "(an exampl(e))".head == '('
res2: Boolean = true
```